# Question About Implied Probability

Tags: probability

In a question about probability, specifically implied probability, I was given the following information: "Let A be some event with odds 3/1 and let its complement have odds 1/1." I wasn't sure what implied probability was, so I searched it and found it was calculated as follows: $denominator / (denominator + numerator)$ (https://help.smarkets.com/hc/en-gb/articles/214058369-How-to-calculate-implied-probability-in-betting). However, given this formula, the implied probability of A is 1/4, while the implied probability of A's complement is 1/2, which does not add up to 1. My question is why is this so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even as betting odds these don't make sense.  Suppose you bet $1$ on the event and $2$ on the complement.  If the event occurs, you net $3-2=1$.  If the event does not occur, you net $2-1=1$.  The bookie who offers these odds will not be in business long.  In general, if you convert the betting odds to the implied probabilities and add up all the results, you will get less than $1$.  Otherwise, you could assure yourself of a profit (or at least of breaking even, if the sum is exactly $1$,) by betting an appropriate amount on every outcome.

Comment: It rather depend on how the odds are written.  "Three to one against" leads to the problems you and @saulspatz see while "Three to one on" produces a different situation where the implied probability is $\frac34$, which added to $\frac12$ still does not get $1$, but does leave a margin for the book maker to make a profit.

Comment: @Henry I've never seen odds quoted that way, though I'm not much of a gambler.  Please tell me where that system is used.

Comment: From https://www.actionnetwork.com/betting-calculators/betting-odds-calculator: "Did you notice those percentages add up to more than 100%? That’s because of the vig, which is a sportsbook’s cut for facilitating your bet."  <--Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: $A$ seems to have "implied probability" $\frac14=25\%$ while $A^c$ seems to have "implied probability" $\frac12=50\%.$ Then $1=P(A)+P(A^c)=0.75,$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @saulspatz  writing "Three to one against" as $3/1$ is typical of British bookmakers.  See [this example](https://sports.ladbrokes.com/event/politics/international/us-elections/2024-us-presidential-election/229683570/all-markets).  By contrast for mathematicians higher odds are associated with higher probabilities

Comment: @Henry "Three to one against" is typical in the US too, in my limited experience.  I meant I've never heard of "three to one on."  Where's that used?

Comment: @saulspatz It is rarely written in letters, but a Google search points to for example [the third paragraph of a stats.se answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/183889/2958) or the [bottom of page 14 of a accountancy paper on gambling](https://www.accountingweb.co.uk/files/oldaweb-downloads/hmrc/Bookmakers.pdf) or [a 1920 Indian newspaper](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3h5DAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA41&lpg=RA3-PA41&dq=%22three+to+one+on%22&source=bl&ots=msToFpSwhi&sig=ACfU3U1FAz0aaznhLdjCXQITFGUUnWTP1w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1suGirPDyAhVBUMAKHfE-A3MQ6AF6BAgREAM)

Comment: @Henry Thank you.